# React native does not reloads after the app is in pause state

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-router-flux

Explanation for the scenario:
I am using react-native-router-flux(4.0.0-beta.31), react-native(0.54.0), react-redux(5.0.7) and redux(4.0.0).
At top is the app.js which has the provider with reducer and redux-thunk, inside that is the router which you can see in [app.js](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker/blob/master/app.js).
And the router file is [router.js](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker/blob/master/router.js). So, when the app loads first the first scene of the tab opens after login screen and then when i press back button the app goes in the backround and unmount of that component executes, but when the app is opened again pressing the app icon nothing of the lifecycle executes. Execution happens as, onenter of the router scene executes and action is called it goes till the reducer but after that none of the component's lifecycle method gets executed. Then when I kill the app and open it again it works fine.

On whatever screen the app is getting killed that particular screen appears after start. Some state is getting persisted. Changed state is getting set in the reducer but mapstatetoprops function is not getting called. Component wise no function is getting executed.

Comment: Could you add to the question part of your code? Perhaps the API call in the component where is the problem, your structure... with it we could help you easier.

Comment: @MateoGuzmán can you guess why would that happen? because only service is creating problem when i disable the service everything works fine. something might be related to the instance not getting created because the oncreate method of my mainapplication is also not getting called when the app starts when the service is on.

Comment: @MateoGuzmán please see the [router](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker/blob/master/router.js)  which is the parent of all components. Above this is the app.js [app.js](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker/blob/master/app.js). It seems there is some other problem as when I press the back button to close the app and then open it again nothing comes even though service is not running so problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think that the problem is not related with React Native. Your router seems good. The problem is in the `TrackingService.java`. Try to split the problem, maybe the service is broken when you close the app because it needs something external to run this, or your config in background is not complete. Try to split and discard possibilities.

Comment: @MateoGuzmán i have updated the question description. Please look and see if you can solve this.